# importing multiple *.csv files into access - every file into separate table

Tags: csv, ms-access, import

I have over a thousand files to import into a ACCESS database.
Every file needs to be imported into separate ACCESS table.
It needs to support importing this files every day, because, there are polish stocks prices, so every day, around 08 p.m. I'm downloading a *.zip file containing 1000 *.csv files, and I'll need to import them another time, to get today's prices.

[image]

I need to have some settings changed, in order to have my data imported correctly.

[image]

next thing is:
[image]

advanced settings:
[image]

how it looks like.

[image]

I don't know how to write these advanced changes in the VBA code.
In EXCEL I could record the macro, and then see the syntax, with the settings I have chosen, but is it possible to do the same in ACCESS ?

There are two codes I've found on the internet.
first:

> Function Impo_allExcel()

```
 Dim my_file As String
 Dim my_path As String

 my_path = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl_csv"
 ChDir (my_path)              'why my_path is inside the brackets??

 my_file = Dir()

 Do While my_file <> ""      'is not empty (<> means not equal to), Excel VBA enters the value into
        'this line above doesn't work, when I'm trying to debug it with F8
   If my_file Like "*.csv" Then
     ' this will import ALL the *.CSV files
     '(one at a time, but automatically) in this folder.
     ' Make sure that's what you want.
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "Contacts_AVDC_NEW", my_path & my_file
     ' what this above line says ? please explain.
    End If
    my_file = Dir()     ' what it means?
  Loop
  End Function
```

second is:

> Function Do_Import_from_CSV()

```
  Dim strPathFile As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strTable As String
  Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

  ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet has field names
  blnHasFieldNames = True
  ' real path to the folder that contains the CSV files
  strPath = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl_csv"

  ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which the data are to be imported
  strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")  'what this line means?

   Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

   ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
   ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
   '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()    'what this means?
  Loop
  End Function
```

Could U please briefly explain these codes for me,
tell me what is the difference between them,
and how can I incorporate the settings I need into these codes,
or into the one that suits me better.
thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you should not be loading 1000 files into 1000 different tables. I'm fairly certain you need to load those 1000 files into _one_ table and add an extra column to differentiate them. Also in your options, you are linking to them. Why would you do that instead of importing them?

Comment: it's my first database I'm biulding.
I thought it's smart to have every stock in it's own column.
How do U suggest this database should look like? If all stocks would be imported into one big table, the ticker column could differentiate the stocks between each other - there would be no need to ad extra column.

Comment: Dir() looks up the next file in your directory, so looping through with my_file seems like you're on yhe right track, but as per Nick's suggestion, put them all into one table, and as you said the ticker value differentiates your records, so no need to add extra columns or tables (that's assuming each of your csv files contains a distinct ticker value)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid,
I understand what both of You guys said to me - to put this data into single column, and use the ticker field/column from every stock file to differentiate between them in this one big 3,5 milion row table. 
OK. Can You Take one of these two provided codes and adapt it, to fit this task in example given above in my post.
Yes, each of my *.CSV files contains a distinct ticker (stock name) value in the very first column.